# How to schedule a transactional email locally?

Tags: magento2, cron, transactional-mail

I want to test any transactional email by a schedule in my local environment.

How could I do that in my local?

Comment: Have you installed email client like postfix ?

Comment: yes, Mailhog @Ajith